# Phantom Lancer illusions use auras?

Tags: dota-2

Does Phantom Lancer's illusions use aura's, like from Vladamir's? Does the lifesteal contribute to PL's health? Do they use aura armor reduction? I'm also curious about Desolation armor reduction, or do the PL illusions *only* do damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Illusions to get a understanding what illusions can do and whatnot.

Lifesteal does not work on them.

Illusions will bestow any auras that the original hero has. However, with the exception of auras that increase Attack Speed or Movement Speed, they usually will not benefit from them.

Comment: @EhevuTov Notably, the only orb that works on illusions (and only then on melee illusions) is Feedback from an item like Diffusal Blade or a built-in modifier like AM's Mana-Break. This is why the item is so core on serious illusion carries like Naga, PL, etc. They also carry the Radiance aura, allowing you to spread the burn to a wider area, which is why Radiance is such a great item on a hero like Spectre.

Comment: @Decency so something like Crusher with it's slow wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @EhevuTov Assuming you mean Sange or Skadi? Sange will not. I am not sure about Skadi.

Comment: No, the only **items** that modify the **attacks** of illusions directly are : diffusial blade, Monkey King Bar(only the true strike, not the stun) , quelling blade, critikal strike items, and the attack range change of aghanims on enchantress.